# Form ng-click is triggering ng-submit

Tags: angularjs

I have a form whose `ng-submit` is to move to the next question.

```
        <form ng-submit="BC.next()" novalidate>
            <input type="submit" value="Next Question"/>
            <button id="previous" ng-click="BC.previous()">Previous Question</button>
```

However, whenever I click on the previous button, after executing, it then triggers the `BC.next()` I'm so confused, does anyone know why this is happening? I even tried closing the `<input type="submit">` tag with a `</input>` but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Prevent the default action of the form when you click the button

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure that all other button in the form that are not submitting it will be from `type="button"`.

```
 <form ng-submit="BC.next()" novalidate>
            <input type="submit" value="Next Question"/>
            <button type="button" id="previous" ng-click="BC.previous()">Previous Question</button>
```

You can see the details: [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

TL;DR for the post: HTML5 defaults `<button>` as `<button type="submit">` so you need to change this manually.

Comment: Wow so interesting!! how did you know that? Is this doucmented somewhere? Or is it expected behavior of javascript?

Comment: Ah thanks for your edit! So that is javascript behavior huh? Stack wont let me accept slution for 8more minutes excuse that please.

Comment: This is one of the first problems when starting to work with Angular & Javascript so you are getting familiar with this really quickly.

Comment: Thanks @Shiklosh! :) I didnt know HTML5 defaulted butto nto type submit this is awesome learning thank you!